# Replace String in between nth and n+1 occurrence of a character in Java

Tags: java

I am having a string with the format as abc_1234_01233456_DC . How we can replace the text which is in between the second and third occurrence of "_" with some other text.

The final output will be abc_1234_78910_DC. I tried with the following code.

```
if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(name)){
        List<String> nameList =  new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(StringUtils.split(name, "_")));
        if(nameList.size()==3){
            nameList.set(2,"78910");
            return StringUtils.join(nameList,"_");
        }
    }
```

Do we have any simple way to implement?

Thanks,
Sri.

Comment: `ArrayUtils.getLength(nameList)==3` <- You don't need any special util to get the length of a list as they already have a `size` method you can just call. Does this method even work with Lists? Anyway, just do `nameList.size()==3`

Comment: Further, there is no need to copy the `List` returned by `Arrays.asList(StringUtils.split(name, "_"))` into another list via `new ArrayList<>(…)`. But anyway, you want to replace a part of the string, you can do it by…replacing the part of the string, `result = input.replaceFirst("(([^_]*+_){2})[^_]*+_", "$178910_")`, without Collection operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The better way - using regex

```
String input = "abc_1234_01233456_DC";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(_([^_]+)){2}").matcher(input);//{2} - number of occurrence
String result = matcher.find() ? new StringBuilder(input).replace(matcher.start(2), matcher.end(2), "78910").toString() : input; //abc_1234_78910_DC
```

That's it

Comment: Looks great. There’s the slightly more efficient alternative `new StringBuilder(input.length() + 5) .append(input, 0, matcher.start(2)).append("78910").append(input, matcher.end(2), input.length()) .toString()` which has less copying overhead. But yours is simpler. But, I’d consider using a conditional, e.g. `String result = matcher.find()? ……: input;`, to have the original string as result if there is no match.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with just `java.lang.String` class.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(getUpdated("abc_1234_01233456_DC", "78910"));
    }

    static String getUpdated(String name, String replacementStr) {
        String parts[] = {};
        if (name != null) {
            parts = name.split("_");
            if (parts.length > 3) {
                parts[2] = replacementStr;
            }
        }
        return String.join("_", parts);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
abc_1234_78910_DC
```

You can also parametrize the delimiter and the part/word number to be replaced e.g.

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(getUpdated("abc_1234_01233456_DC", "78910", "_", 3));
    }

    /**
     * Replaces the nth part/word and returns the updated string
     * 
     * @param str            - The string to be updated
     * @param replacementStr - The replacement string
     * @param delimiter      - The delimiter to split the string on
     * @param nth            - The part/word to be replaced
     * @return the updated string
     */
    static String getUpdated(String str, String replacementStr, String delimiter, int nth) {
        String parts[] = {};
        if (str != null) {
            parts = str.split(Pattern.quote(delimiter), nth + 1);
            if (parts.length > nth) {
                parts[nth - 1] = replacementStr;
            }
        }
        return String.join(delimiter, parts);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
abc_1234_78910_DC
```

Answer (score 1):

Just using the Java standard indexOf method of the String class you can easily achieve what you're looking for:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String test = "abc_1234_01233456_DC";
    final String replacement = "78910";
    System.out.println(replace("_", 2, test, replacement));
}
    
public static String replace(String cue, int occur, String input, String replacement) {
    int index = 0;
    while (occur-- > 0) {
        index = input.indexOf(cue, index);
        if (-1 == index) {
            return input;
        }
        index++;
    }

    int nextIndex = input.indexOf(cue, index);
    if (-1 == nextIndex) {
        nextIndex = input.length();
    }
    return input.substring(0,  index) + replacement + input.substring(nextIndex);
}
```